# Can I write a library that includes a default header file unless the user specifies their own?

Tags: c++, arduino, header, include, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a library for arduino that (among other things) transmits data to another device over a serial bus. I'm using a union of a struct and a byte array so the users can do things like:

`myData.dataStruct.temp = getTemp();`

and then later they can just use:

`myLib.sendData(data);`

So my thought was to have a generic header (default header?) that defined a generic struct and union that users could get started with.

**genericDataStruct.h:**

```c
#ifndef Use_Custom_Data_Struct // Only use these declarations if no custom data struct

# ifndef DataPacket_generic_h
# define DataPacket_generic_h

typedef struct UserDataStruct_t{
    char            header[NSL_PACKET_HEADER_LENGTH];
    int8_t          b1;       ///<  b1  (Generic packet byte  1 of 35 )
    int8_t          b2;       ///<  b2  (Generic packet byte  2 of 35 )
    int8_t          b3;       ///<  b3  (Generic packet byte  3 of 35 )
    // ... etc
    int8_t          b35;      ///<  b35 (Generic packet byte 35 of 35 )

};


typedef union DataPacket_t {
    UserDataStruct_t payloadData;
    byte Packet[sizeof(UserDataStruct_t)];
};

# endif /* ThinSat_DataPacket_generic_h */

#endif /* Use_Custom_Data_Struct */
```

The library functions use these typedefs, so currently myLib.h is including genericDataStruct.h

**myLib.h:**

```
#include "genericDataStruct.h"

// ... later on

class myLib
{

public:
    myLib();
    bool    sendData(DataPacket_t data);
}
```

The intent was to let the user do things one of two ways:

**Use the generic/default data structure:**

```c
#include "myLib.h"

DataPacket_t myData;

// later on

myData.payloadData.b1 = 0xFF;
```

And then they get on with their life, or...

*Use their own semantically relevant data structure:*

```c++
#define Use_Custom_Data_Struct
#include "customDataStruct.h"
#include "myLib.h"

DataPacket_t myData;

// later on

myData.payloadData.temp = 98.6;
```

When I try to run this I get compiler errors because of multiple `typedef struct UserDataStruct_t` in my generic header and the user header...

It looks like I'm barking up the wrong tree here. I think #defines don't get shared between files by the preprocessor? So that probably means that include guards won't really do what I want.

I can't extern a struct declaration/definition (I don't think...) so I'm at a bit of a loss.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it'd be greatly appreciated. Open to code or architecture changes (any help, really).

Comment: Your code runs fine. https://repl.it/repls/OrdinaryGrownBots

Comment: I forgot to add that myLib.h includes the genericDataStruct.h (needs the typedefs) - I’ll update the question with that detail.

Comment: @MoeTheCat Just curious: why `int8_t b1; int8_t b2; int8_t b3; ... int8_t b35;` instead of `int8_t b[35]`?

Comment: @L. F. it's a fair question. The intent is for the structure to have fields with semantic meaning, but I can't know the users' intent a priori. So I just used those field names (which are sort of semantically meaningful in this generic case) to keep the usage the same ```myData.payloadData.b35 = 0xFF```. I suppose the user could also write to the byte array portion of the union and just address the correct element like ```myData.packet[35] = 0xFF```   -- hope that made sense outside my twisted brain

Comment: @MoeTheCat It seems what you are trying to achieve is the exact problem *templates* solve.

Comment: @L.F. - ahh, an area about which I know absolutely nothing. I'll try to look into templates to see how to apply them. Forgive the noobish question, but is there any reason to suspect that I couldn't apply templates to an Arduino library? I'm not sure what the IDE does under the hood (I think it's still gcc ultimately, so hopefully no issues)

Comment: @MoeTheCat: Templates aren’t inherently incompatible with any hardware; while “fringe” hardware often has older compilers, basic template behavior has been standard since 1998.

Comment: Note that reading from the union member that wasn’t last written is [undefined behavior](https://adriann.github.io/undefined_behavior.html), although it is rather widely (albeit partially) supported as an extension.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks, I hadn't considered that. Fortunately my `sendData()` modifies the header bytes from the byte array before reading from it. Complete luck due to the demands of the logic, but hopefully that keeps me in defined behavior as a bonus!

Comment: Yes, formally it's _undefined_ , practically it's the only purpose of a union. If you use it to send byte arrays over the wire and reinterpret it with a similar union on the receiver side, you are heavily hardware-dependent. But that's the same as using a reinterpret-cast of one pointer type  to another one.

Answer (score 0):

## genericDataStruct.h:

```
#ifndef USERSTRUCT
typedef struct UserDataStruct_t{
    char            header[NSL_PACKET_HEADER_LENGTH];
    int8_t          b1;       ///<  b1  (Generic packet byte  1 of 35 )
    int8_t          b2;       ///<  b2  (Generic packet byte  2 of 35 )
    int8_t          b3;       ///<  b3  (Generic packet byte  3 of 35 )
    // ... etc
    int8_t          b35;      ///<  b35 (Generic packet byte 35 of 35 )

};
#endif   
typedef union DataPacket_t {
    UserDataStruct_t payloadData;
    byte Packet[sizeof(UserDataStruct_t)];
};
```

## customDatastruct.h

```
#define USERSTRUCT
typedef struct UserDataStruct_t{
    char            header[NSL_PACKET_HEADER_LENGTH];
    float           temp;   // assuming byte order and float representation fit
// ...
};
```

However, sizes of `UserDatastruct_t` must match, as while compiling `myLib.cpp` customDatastruct.h is unknown and  myLib::sendData simply uses the 
`byte Packet[sizeof(UserDataStruct_t)];` part of the union.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I had tried include guards, but I'd done it around the union declarations, too. Your method complies in my test project (which is a big step forward!) - Ill see if I can get it working in my library. Now I get compiler warnings about multiple typedefs for UserDataStruct_t, but it did compile. Any idea about cleaning up those warnings?

Comment: The include order matters: in this case customDatastruct.h must come before genericDataStruct in every .cpp that uses customDatastruct.h

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense, but I think it puts me back in the position of having the users modify the library files directly, as myLib.cpp will have to include the genericDataStruct.h. - I think living with compiler warnings is acceptable for the time being.